# Is there any way to capture application exit event in vb.net windows form system?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In C#, I used to capture the application exit event with the following code in program.cs.

```
   static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "The application was closed at :" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "."; 


    }
```

What is the equivalent of this in VB.NET?

I want to close the database connection if it is open by any chance in the application exit event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
AddHandler Application.ApplicationExit, AddressOf OnApplicationExit

Private Sub OnApplicationExit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' When the application is exiting, write the application data to the 
    ' user file and close it.
    WriteFormDataToFile()

    Try 
        ' Ignore any errors that might occur while closing the file handle.
        userData.Close()
    Catch 
    End Try 
End Sub
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Hi, I think this will give me form closing event. I need application closed event. There are hundreds of forms in my application. I want to write the code at one place only. Thanks.

Comment: ,thanks for the update. In C#, I would have written this snippet in program.cs. Where do I write this code snippet in vb.net?

Comment: however, you can add a new module and select it as the startup object.

First, right click on the project and choose Add: Module.... You can name the module anything you like, but I named it Program.vb to be consistent with the C# default. Paste in the following code:

Answer (score 3):

Double click on `MyProject` and click the `Application Tab` and then click the `View Application Events` button. There is an event for [Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/036kk0as%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) - which fires when the application is closing.